# UIButton inside UITableViewCell not working in simulator (iOS 14)

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

after updating Xcode to version 12, every UIButton that added to UITableViewCell like this:

```
self.addSubview(someButton)
```

in simulator(iOS version 14) the button not working(when user tap on the button nothing happening) but in real device everything works fine. when I added UIButton to cell like this everything works fine even in simulator:

```
self.contentView.addSubview(receptionButton)
```

why this is happening? and am I doing right by adding UIButton this way (self.contentView.addSubview) to UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and am I doing right by adding UIButton this way
> (self.contentView.addSubview) to UITableViewCell?

**YES**.

That is the most correct way! You can add your subviews to `self`(cell itself), directly, like in your first code block, BUT, you will 100% hit a bug in the future (I did), like what you've just experienced now.

---

> why this is happening?

This is the best explanation that I could find from Apple:

`The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content that the cell displays. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they position appropriately as the cell transitions in to and out of editing mode.`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview